# Assigning an XML query result in SQL Server to an XML type variable produces an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, sqlxml

SQL: 2008 Compatability: SQL 2008 OS: Vista
The following query works just fine and produces an XML:

```
with Q1 as
    (select Job, Site from JJobs where Job > 602700)
select * from Q1 where Job = 602720
    for xml path('Detail'), type
```

I need to put this into a function that returns an XML variable so, I change to:

```
declare @xOut XML;
set @xOut =
with Q1 as
    (select Job, Site from JJobs where Job > 602700)
select * from Q1 where Job = 602720
    for xml path('Detail'), type
```

This produces the error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
The query works but the assignment errors and indicates a problem with the query.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @xOut XML;

with Q1 as
(
  select Job, Site 
  from JJobs 
  where Job > 602700
)
select @xOut = (
               select * 
               from Q1 
               where Job = 602720
               for xml path('Detail'), type
               );
```